# How do you enable batch inserts in hibernate?

Tags: java, database, performance, hibernate, batch-processing

With hibernate, when I attempt to enable batch inserts with

```
  <property name="jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
```

I get the following output:

```
 [...] cfg.SettingsFactory INFO  - JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
 [...] cfg.SettingsFactory INFO  - Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
```

And then this:

```
 [...] jdbc.AbstractBatcher DEBUG - Executing batch size: 1
```

never more than `batch size: 1` basically.

Am I missing a setting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out what was missing in this case was:

```
<property name="order_inserts">true</property>
```

ref: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2374413, https://stackoverflow.com/a/5240930/32453
Or possibly hibernate.order_inserts.

Now I see

```
 [...] cfg.SettingsFactory INFO  - Order SQL inserts for batching: enabled
 ...
 [...] Executing batch size: 2
```

Much more frequently (anything greater than 1 basically means it's successfully doing batch inserts).

hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data may also be useful.

jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/batch?rewriteBatchedStatements=true type connection strings might also be related somehow.

https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2374413 and also see
[Hibernate batch size confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6687422/hibernate-batch-size-confusion)

Comment: This is not 100% correct: even the batch size of 1 means that Hibernate is using the Batching API of JDBC and, I've tested this, it's **much** faster than the regular API even at size 1. Tested with Oracle and Postgresql.

Comment: Ok I suppose this means that initially for me batch processing was "turned on" but not as effective as it otherwise would be. Good to know.

Answer (score 16):

To enable batching for both INSERT and UPDATE statements, you need to set all the following Hibernate properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=30
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_updates=true
```

If you can use a `SEQUENCE`, then you should not use `IDENTITY` entity identifier generator, since it disables batch fetching.

If you cannot use a `SEQUENCE` (e.g. MySQL), then try using a separate mechanism to enable batch inserts (e.g. JDBC) instead of using the `TABLE` generator which does not scale and has a high-performance penalty.