# How can I do massive insert using Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am pretty new to **Spring Data JPA** and **Hibernate** and I have the following problem with massive record insertion.

I have the following situation:

1) A **RoomMediaDAO** Spring Data JPA interface:

```
@Repository
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public interface RoomMediaDAO extends JpaRepository<RoomMedia, Long> {

   ....................................................................
   ....................................................................
   ....................................................................
}
```

2) Into another class I use this **RoomMediaDAO** to persist a list of **RoomMedia** object. The list is pretty big and heavy because contains many object and each oof these objects contains a **byte[]** field representing a **BLOB** on the mapped table.

So I have the follosing statment that persist the **List mediaListToBeInserted**:

```
roomMediaDAO.save(mediaListToBeInserted);
```

It work fine but it is very slow because it perform the insert one by one, infact in the console I can see something like this:

```
Hibernate: insert into room_media (description, media, id_room, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into room_media (description, media, id_room, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into room_media (description, media, id_room, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into room_media (description, media, id_room, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into room_media (description, media, id_room, time_stamp) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
............................................................................
............................................................................
............................................................................
```

So this is not a good solution.

How can I say to Hibernate to insert more record with a single insert statment? I mean can I do something like this using Hibernate?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable ( Column1, Column2 ) VALUES
( Value1, Value2 ), 
( Value1, Value2 ),
( Value1, Value2 ),
.................................
.................................
.................................
( Value1, Value2 )
```

I absolutly need something like this to improve the performance of my batch.

Comment: Look - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011343/how-do-you-enable-batch-inserts-in-hibernate

Comment: How many is "massive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [link](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html) provides a detailed explanation about different ways of performing batch inserts. Mentioned in Italics are some problems with these approaches.

1. Using **batch_size** (13.1 section in the link provided) - In case you've alternating inserts (non-sequential inserts into a table, Table1 followed by Table2 and again Table1 and soon) then remember to use `order_inserts`. 
   Also, *doesn't work if Generator is of type `Identity`*.
2. Using **StatelessSession** for insertion. (13.3) - Inserted values are not stored in First Level Cache. 
   *May result in data aliasing effects (due to missing FLC), Also bypasses Hibernate's event model and interceptors*.
3. Using **DML-style operations** 
   (*Insert with Select is Only supported, not values*)
4. If you're using **Postgres** (Or for other DB, check if those DB's support any **Bulk insert Operation**, then leveraging on that is a very good option). Making use of [Copy manager](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/publicapi/org/postgresql/copy/CopyManager.html) features to upload all this data in one shot. [Comparison of Performance](http://rostislav-matl.blogspot.in/2011/08/fast-inserts-to-postgresql-with-jdbc.html).
   *Make Sure the PushbackReader used is not overflown. I misjudged this and had to face some prod. issues with BufferOverflow.*

PS : Each of the approaches have their adv & dis-adv. Choose the one that suits you.