# Transaction with many deletes followed by many inserts with Hibernate and Spring

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, deadlock

I use spring boot + MySQL5 database.

There is a periodic service that runs and need to do the following transaction:

1. Delete records (with condition)
2. Insert records

In addition another service does select queries and should see a snapshot of the records without interfering with the delete+insert transactions.

I have the following code:

```
@Service
public class BulkInsert
{

    public static final String DELETE_ALL_ROWS_QUERY = "DELETE FROM GnsEntity where is_synced = true and was_removed = false";

    @Inject
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void save(List<GnsEntity> gnsEntityList)
    {
        Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query entity = session.createQuery(DELETE_ALL_ROWS_QUERY);
        entity.executeUpdate();
        for (int i = 0; i < gnsEntityList.size(); ++i)
        {
            try
            {
                session.persist(gnsEntityList.get(i));
            }
            catch(NonUniqueObjectException nonUniEx)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

In general it seems to work good.. though a lot of times there's a deadlock exception and I have no clue why..

Thats why I was wondering if my code is relatively fine?

I get the following errors every now and then:

> DEBUG","message":"Creating new transaction with name
>   [com.ddd.swiss.microservices.gnssynchronizer.BulkInsert.save]:
>   PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT","service":"GNSSynchronizer","instanceId":"1","application":"Start","space":"ngampel","class":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager","thread":"pool-3-thread-1","X-B3-TraceId":"5db000bfb3de1a6d49a53edd707419a0","X-B3-SpanId":"49a53edd707419a0"}
>   {"@timestamp":"2019-10-23T07:27:24.318Z","logLevel":"DEBUG","message":"Opened
>   new EntityManager
>   [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@5a445da1] for JPA
>   transaction","service":"GNSSynchronizer","instanceId":"1","application":"Start","space":"ngampel","class":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager","thread":"pool-3-thread-1","X-B3-TraceId":"5db000bfb3de1a6d49a53edd707419a0","X-B3-SpanId":"49a53edd707419a0"}
>   {"@timestamp":"2019-10-23T07:27:24.318Z","logLevel":"DEBUG","message":"begin","service":"GNSSynchronizer","instanceId":"1","application":"Start","space":"ngampel","class":"org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl","thread":"pool-3-thread-1","X-B3-TraceId":"5db000bfb3de1a6d49a53edd707419a0","X-B3-SpanId":"49a53edd707419a0"}
>   {"@timestamp":"2019-10-23T07:27:24.319Z","logLevel":"DEBUG","message":"Exposing
>   JPA transaction as JDBC transaction
>   [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@241c36b8]","service":"GNSSynchronizer","instanceId":"1","application":"Start","space":"ngampel","class":"org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager","thread":"pool-3-thread-1","X-B3-TraceId":"5db000bfb3de1a6d49a53edd707419a0","X-B3-SpanId":"49a53edd707419a0"}
>   {"@timestamp":"2019-10-23T07:27:24.319Z","logLevel":"DEBUG","message":"delete
>   from gns_entity where is_synced=1 and
>   was_removed=0","service":"GNSSynchronizer","instanceId":"1","application":"Start","space":"ngampel","class":"org.hibernate.SQL","thread":"pool-3-thread-1","X-B3-TraceId":"5db000bfb3de1a6d49a53edd707419a0","X-B3-SpanId":"49a53edd707419a0"}
>   {"@timestamp":"2019-10-23T07:27:25.451Z","logLevel":"DEBUG","message":"could
>   not execute statement
>   [n/a]","stackTrace":"com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLTransactionRollbackException:
>   Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting
>   transaction\n\tat
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Nativ

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just for information purposes, how long does this service take to run, and when is it being run?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when the delete+insert is working its about 1 minute..  its running with schedule execution of spring,waiting for 3 min after its done

Comment: Where are the inserts?

Comment: session.persist()

Comment: You mention your periodic transaction and the read only service, but given that your periodic query is checking the conditions is_synced and was_removed, is there is fact an additional access to the data that is modifying these columns ?

Comment: in the future yes.. right now not.. so it deletes everything..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it looks okay what I did? given my requirements?

Comment: You are inside a cicle... I suggest to you to flush the session. Let's suppose you have a `batch_size` constant equals to `25` you can do something like this just after the persist(): `if(i==batch_size){session.flush(); session.clear()}` More information can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41417525/how-can-i-do-massive-insert-using-hibernate