# How to save multiple entities in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

in my Java web application, I would like to persist every 100 instances of the save entity at once, what is the best way to do that? I have some time constraints that I have to respect, the persisting operation should be fast. I there any method faster than the others? Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is batch insert into database using JPA. These topics have already been brought up, these will help you:

- [JPA/Hibernate bulk(batch) insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773302/jpa-hibernate-bulkbatch-insert)
- [Batch inserts with JPA/EJB3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448181/batch-inserts-with-jpa-ejb3)

## Summary

- **Using Hibernate's batch inserts.** Hiberate provides methods for [batch inserting and updating](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch15.html) entities.
- **Disabling automatic ID generation.**
  If you generate ids automatically, Hibernate executes query for each entity to generate the primary key.

## Opinion

Basically I think that disabling automatic ID generation is a bad idea. You can take most of Hibernate's batch methods, but this will not save you much of performance.

After this is done, I suggest you looking for optimizations in other layers of your application.

Comment: I finally try your solution and it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Rami, glad to hear. Which solution did you use eventually?

Comment: Hey @JMelnik, I am using batch insert now, so instead of saving each entity, I am taking profit of the one-to-may relation and when I am saving a parent entity, all its child are saved with it. Although, I am sill using the automatic ID generation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Hibernate intergarated with Spring, you can use `HibernateTemplate#saveOrUpdateAll`

```
 mHibernateTemplate.saveOrUpdateAll(entities);
```

Comment: What is the version of this syntax ? Having this code with Hibernate 3.x now that am upgrading to HIbernate 5.x this option is not available. What is the alternative ?

Comment: incorrect. try to specify version. seems like saveOrUpdateAll is not avaiable