# What is the equivalent of AbstractBatcher in Hibernate 4.*

Tags: java, hibernate, logging

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773302/jpa-hibernate-bulkbatch-insert) suggests that a class AbstractBatcher in Hibernate is responsible for Batching insert statements, and that it does some logging when it kicks into action.

But as far as I can tell this class only exists until Hibernate 3.x and I can't find it in Hibernate 4.x

Where is the equivalent class? And does it still do some logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the class you are looking for is `BatchingBatch`

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/batch/internal/BatchingBatch.html

Looking at the code, I think it may even contain the line `Executing batch size: %s`

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.hibernate/com.springsource.org.hibernate/4.0.0/org/hibernate/engine/jdbc/batch/internal/BatchingBatch.java